# Converting function from Python to C

Tags: python, c

This function is written in python. I am trying to measure performance between Python and C.
Would it be possible for someone fluent in C to help convert this function to C?

**The input string**

0T1M1L1BtT1L1BtT1TtT1B1T1H1E1I1PtT1B2Z1C1L1G1NtTtNtT2Z1M1T2ZtT2W1PtT1T1C1PtTzutT2Z1P1B2Z1L1G1N

**The output after decode**

This is a sample string & that we are = testing

This is the function in python:

```
def decode(encstr):
        # Number of characters in string should be even
        # If it's not - remove last character
        if (len(encstr) % 2 != 0):
                encstr = encstr[:-1] # length of string - 1
        strlen = len(encstr)

        i = 0
        decrypted = []
        while (i < strlen):
                # get character at position i
                cc = encstr[i];
                # get integer representing the Unicode code point of the character
                cch = ord(cc)
                nch = ord(encstr[i + 1])
                if cc == '0':
                        v = nch
                elif cc == 'z':
                        v = cch - nch + 56
                elif cc in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']:
                        v = (cch - 49) * 25 + 181 - nch
                else:
                        v = cch - nch

                if(v < 0):
                        v = (v % 256) + 256

                if v > 255:
                        v = v % 256

                # append the decrypted character
                decrypted.append(chr(v))

                i += 2

        return ''.join(decrypted)
```

Comment: Very nice way of saying `translate python code into C`.

Comment: Its not very hard, where are you stuck ?

Comment: I can tell you the result: The C code will trash the Python code. That Python code is not written particularly well.

Comment: What do you mean by trash? Meaning it will perform way better?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How could you _conclude_ that without looking at the C code? :)

Comment: @Gabson, actually I haven't written any C code. I was wondering if someone who knows C quite well can maybe write it up in 5 - 10 minutes . I have already converted it from PHP to Python, and measured performance.

Comment: @devnull: Even the most naive implementation in C will be faster than that terrible, terrible Python.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Might you be able to point out what areas of the function could be written better to achieve better performance?

Comment: Instead of doing all that character math, use dicts (one dict per algo, and one dict to hold all the other dicts) that have `(cc, nc)` as a key and the appropriate result as the value. Startup will take a little longer as the data is compiled, but the actual decoding will *fly* (not to mention it will collapse into one big genex).

Comment: (Eyeballing result) 8-12 lines of functional C..?

Comment: @RonBuenavida - Do you have feedback for any of the people who _actually offered an answer_?

Comment: Aww -- just when I was uploading my answer (14 lines in the main part) it got closed!

Comment: .. Since the OP mentioned 'benchmarking', mine took 0.007439 sec for 10,000 loops.

Comment: (3 min later) a further tweak took it down to 0.004826 sec for 10,000 loops. Okay, had my 10 minutes of fun, going to do something useful now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naive, 1 to 1 translation because I'm lazy and bored and don't want to work on what I'm supposed to be working on (C99 or later):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>

void decode( const char *encstr, 
             size_t decrypt_len, 
             char decrypt[ static decrypt_len ] )
{
  assert( encstr );

  size_t len = strlen( encstr );
  //
  // Create a local copy of the encrypted string, since we want to 
  // modify the input below
  //
  char lencstr[len + 1];
  strcpy( lencstr, encstr );

  if ( len % 2 )
    lencstr[len - 1] = 0;

  const char *cc = lencstr;
  const char *nc = cc + 1;

  while ( *cc )
  {
    int v;

    if ( *cc == '0' )
      v = *nc;
    else if ( *cc == 'z' )
      v = *cc - *nc + 56;
    else if ( isdigit( *cc )  )
      v = (*cc - 49) * 25 + 181 - *nc;
    else
      v = *cc - *nc;

    if ( v < 0 )
      v = ( v % 256 ) + 256;
    else if ( v > 255 )
      v = v % 256;
    *decrypt++ = (char) v;
    cc += 2;
    nc += 2;
  }
  *decrypt = 0;
}

int main( void )
{
  const char *enc = "0T1M1L1BtT1L1BtT1TtT1B1T1H1E1I1PtT1B2Z1C1L1G1NtTt"
                    "NtT2Z1M1T2ZtT2W1PtT1T1C1PtTzutT2Z1P1B2Z1L1G1N";
  char dec[ strlen(enc) + 1 ];

  printf( "Encrypted string: %s\n", enc );
  decode( enc, sizeof dec, dec );
  printf( "Decrypted string: %s\n", dec );
  return 0;
}
```

Build and output:

```
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/decoder: !g
gcc -o decoder -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror decoder.c
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/decoder: ./decoder
Encrypted string: 0T1M1L1BtT1L1BtT1TtT1B1T1H1E1I1PtT1B2Z1C1L1G1NtTtNtT2Z1M1T2ZtT2W1PtT1T1C1PtTzutT2Z1P1B2Z1L1G1N
Decrypted string: This is a sample string & that we are = testing
```

Comment: Only one thing I am not sure about, `char decrypt[ static decrypt_len ] )` didn't work for me.  I had to write it _without_ the `static` keyword.

Comment: @ryyker: Interesting. Which compiler? I built with gcc using std=c99 (as shown above). The presence of `static` within the `[]` is a C99-ism; it specifies that the actual argument corresponding to `decrypt` be an array with *at least* that many elements. I'd be surprised if the compiler accepted all the other C99-isms (VLAs, mixed declarations and code) but blew up on that one thing.

Comment: I am using a C99'ish compiler from NI, LabWindows/CVI.  It does allow me to use variables to initialize an array, but I could not use the `static` keyword.  ***'ish*** because it includes many, but not all, C99 extensions.  I guess I just bumped into one that they did not include.  Your code works great though when I remove `static`!

Comment: Very nice work John. It works fantastic! I will post benchmarks as i did in John Zwinck answer.

Comment: @RonBuenavida: Note that John Zwinck's solution is probably a helluva lot safer (not to mention more elegant) than my C equivalent.  There's a reason I'm using `const`s and `static`s and `assert`s all over the place, and even with that there's still room for major problems (for example, the `decode` method simply assumes that the target is large enough to handle the decrypted string; as written, all that's being verified is that the target is actually an *array*).  That could be avoided by allocating the target array in `decode`, but that opens you up to other issues.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than writing your own C extension to improve the performance, why not use ones already written?  Of course I'm talking about NumPy!

```
import numpy as np

def decode(encstr):
    arr = np.array(encstr, 'c').view(np.uint8) # to ASCII codes
    out = np.empty(len(encstr) / 2, np.uint8)

    out[:] = arr[::2] - arr[1::2] # v = cch - nch, default case                                                         

    mask = np.where(arr == ord('0'))[0] # cc == '0'                                                                     
    out[mask / 2] = arr[mask + 1] # v = nch                                                                             

    mask = np.where(arr == ord('z'))[0] # cc == 'z'                                                                     
    out[mask / 2] = arr[mask] - arr[mask + 1] + 56 # cch - nch + 56                                                     

    mask = np.where(np.logical_and(arr >= ord('1'), arr <= ord('9')))[0] # cc in ['1'..'9']                             
    out[mask / 2] = (arr[mask] - ord('1')) * 25 + 181 - arr[mask + 1] # (cch - ord('1')) * 25 + 181 - nch               

    return ''.join(out.view('c')) # back from ASCII codes
```

This is missing a feature or two from the original code (I'm sure you can add them back if you really need them), but it works fine for the given input sample.

Oh, and in case it's not clear what is going on here: I've vectorized the algorithm, recognizing that the pairs of characters are all independent, so NumPy can be used to perform the conditional operations across the entire string at once, with no iteration in Python itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. I ran a test to check performance with numpy on my local machine. Awesome, it actually runs almost twice as fast. So old code does about 9,000 decodes every 10 secs, and with numpy and your code it does about 16,000 decodes every 10 secs. Really Awesome!! I would really give you the points, but since John Bode wrote it in C, which conforms to the question, i guess I must give it to him. But really awesome work !! I wish it was possible to split to two correct answers!

Comment: @RonBuenavida - If this answer helped at all, in lieu of setting to _the_ answer, its also okay to up-click.  That at least puts some points up for John.